# Swapping using a third variable in Java

Tags: java

What is the need to use a third variable to swap numbers? I am sorry, but I don't get it.

Here is the sample code I have for sorting elements of an array based on length of each element. As you can see here, I am using a third variable, and swapping the elements of the array. I have a different implementation for this program that works, but I found the below example online, and would like to understand what is swapping useful for? If someone could explain that to me, it would be great.

```
public class StringSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = new String[] { "abcd", "dexter", "stringsortexample", "fruit", "apple","car" };              
        compareArrayElements(arr);      

        System.out.println("The strings in the sorted order of length are: ");
        for (String sortedArray : arr) {
            System.out.println(sortedArray);
        }
    }

    public static void compareArrayElements(String[] arr) {
        String temp = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if (arr[i].length() > arr[j].length())
                {
                    temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: "What is the need to use a third variable to swap numbers?" because in general it wouldn't be possible otherwise!

Comment: Okay agree. In the above example, what is the swapping actually doing? Can you explain in the code why it is needed?

Comment: @MitchWheat- You can swap without using a third variable.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not make sense.

Comment: @R.J. see "because in general ". I'm well aware of the XOR 'swap'. Care to show how to swap 2 integers without using another variable (without overflow or using the XOR of both values in a temp)?

Comment: Imagine you have two water barrels, and now you want to swap water between two water barrels, you need one more barrel.

Comment: My question is not regarding whether or not swapping can be done using a third variable. What I'd like to know is why is swapping needed here? How does it help? @Mitch Wheat - It is not off topic as I have seen several online examples where they use swapping. This could be useful for people in the future too. If you could answer it.

Comment: Mostly swap will be used in sorting a collection

Comment: Even in general, its possible. `a = a + b; b = a - b;a = a - b;`. This is a swap.

Comment: what about overflow? Kaboom!!!! That technique leads to hard to understand code, and is a bug waiting to happen. AND I wonder if it is even faster?!!

Comment: You should go through [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html).

Comment: @RongNK - I like your explanation.Please explain me the code on how swapping is helping here. That is what I'd like to know. Sorry, I don't expect to be spoon fed, but I am not getting the point here on why we need to do it this way. I know there are multiple other ways, but I want to understand the concept of swapping, and when it could be useful.

Comment: Sorry, see answer by @aga.

Comment: @R.J - that is not what "in general" means. That trick only works in one case: integers - but not for floats, strings, or any other object.

Comment: I believe you have poorly worded your question. It's not clear whether you are asking about alternative ways of swapping without using the third variable, or whether your question it's about what does the swap do in that specific code.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't juggle in Java!

Think of each variable as a hand that can "hold" one value; e.g. a ball.

If you have two hands and two balls, the only way to switch the balls to the opposite hands involves throwing one of the balls up in the air (or something like that).  But there is no "throw a value into the air" operation in Java.

If you can't juggle you need a third hand (or some other temporary holding place) to swap the balls.  And in Java terms, that means a temporary variable.

<sup>For the record, I found this analogy very useful when I was learning to program.  But don't take it too far :-).</sup>

---

(In fact, if we are talking about integers, there is a mathematical trick that you can use to swap numbers ... involving [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm) ... but it doesn't work in general.)

Comment: Thank you for the excellent explanation Stephen C.

Answer (score 6):

```
temp = arr[i];
arr[i] = arr[j];
arr[j] = temp;
```

That is the part of swapping. Without a temporary temp variable you would lose information on the go.

Example: int a = 5, b = 10;

Now exchange a and b without temp: a = b; --> a = 10, b = 10 -> 5 is lost no way to retrieve or get it. Or lets try: b = a; --> a = 5, b = 5 -> 10 is lost, no way to retrieve it.

With temp:

- temp = a; --> a = 5, b = 10, temp = 5.
- a = b; --> a = 10, b = 10, temp = 5.
- b = temp; --> a = 10, b = 5, temp = 5.
- a and b are now swapped.

That's it. The temporary variable stores the original state of one variable since this state gets overridden and lost when the variable is assigned with its new state (or value).

In your example you use swapping to xchange the position of a number (information) with a number of a different position. Here you have a sorting algorithm that falls in the category of [Selection Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) (and not [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) as other answers suggested).

Watch the animated image at the Bubble Sort link and you get an idea of swapping and then take a look at the Selection Sort link to understand what is going on here.

In your code sample the algorithm checks for the first position and compares it with any other position in the array. If it founds a smaller value as the current one in the first position, it swaps both numbers. After one iteration of the outer loop (the inner loop was done completely for the first time) the first position in your array holds the smallest value in the whole array since if it was bigger it was swapped with a smaller one and if you tested all values on it it contains the smallest one.

On the next run (i = 0++ = 1) in the loop the rest of the array (i + 1 = 2) is tested against the second position (i = 1). So after the second iteration index 1 (arr[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort)) contains the second smallest number (and index 0, arry[0] contains the smallest). This is done until all indexes of the array are processed this way - actually the last one can not be checked with others since it is indeed the last one - and as a result the array is sorted.

Answer (score 4):

The piece of code you have here is well known [bubble-sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). It's the algorithm used to sort the values of an array/list. This algorithm compares every pair of adjacent variables and swaps them if they are in wrong order. There is a small animated picture in the article to help you get a grasp of what a swapping is, take a look at it.
In `python`, for example, you can make a swap of two variables w/o usage of temporary variable, like so:

```
a, b = 1, 2
a, b = b, a # b is 1 and a is 2 now
```

But in Java and other languages with C-like syntax that I know (C, C++, C#) when you want to swap two variables, you need to store value of the first variable in a temporary variable, assign value of second variable to first variable, and then assign stored in a temporary variable value (which was, in fact, value of first variable) to the second variable. This is how it works.

Comment: OT: if you use BubbleSort (ever) you get a special place in programmer hell!! ;)

Comment: This is not bubble sort it is a form of selection sort but very inefficient in terms of xchange. Good way to keep starters thinking. Cudos to the guy running the lesson.

Comment: And bubble sort is what I use quite some time and I am paid for programming :). Bubble sort is easy to implement and easy to go. It is also sometimes the fastest since nowadays small arrays fit the cache of the CPU completely and it is faster to swap variables close to each other using registers than xchanging positions that are far away.

Comment: @MartinKersten Programmers shouldn't write sorts by hand. Period. It has been proven that even senior developers almost always write them incorrectly. It is the job of mature generic libraries unless it can be demonstrated by profiling that something else is necessary.

Comment: Well programmers should do several things and shouldnt do some others. Believe me thats what they tell you inside in and out. But sometimes you just implement it. As I said there are some cases and yes after profiling and doing proper unit testing. And no i never found myself screwing up bubble sort :)

Answer (score 2):

```
temp = arr[i];            
arr[i]= arr[j];            
arr[j]= temp;
```

you just asume that 
    arr[i]=5;
    arr[j]=6;
if you try to swap with out temp variable.
Then you will lose the data like
    arr[i]=arr[j];//arr[i]=5 and arr[j]=5
    arr[j]=arr[i];// both have vale 5.
I think that you understand the idea of temp variable

Answer (score 1):

Let's just say you tried to swap without using a third variable.

```
arr[i] = arr[j];
arr[j] = arr[i];
```

There is an obvious problem here. Because you assigned arr[j] to arr[i] and vice versa, they equal each other. The third variable ensures you temporarily save the contents of the variable you overwrite and then you can assign it to the other variable.

Answer (score 1):

Let `a=1, b=2, c;`

`c=a`;
means `c=1`;

Let `a` empty.
`a=b`;
means `a=2`;

Let `b` empty.
`b=c`;
means `b=1`;

you can see values of `a` and `b` swapped.

Answer (score 1):

Third variable will help you on swapping of 2 values especially on strings.

```
Step 1: Move first value to temp (third variable in your case ); 
step 2: Move second value to first variable.
step 3: Move temp value to first variable.
```

In numbers cases you may find code some times without any third variable. In such cases it works as below:

```
for (int i=0;i<a.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < a.length; j++) {
        if (a[i]>a[j]){
            a[i] = a[i]+a[j];
            a[j]= a[i]-a[j];
            a[i]= a[i]-a[j];
        }
    }
}
```

Here no need any third variable.

Answer (score 0):

Third variable is to temporarily store the value you want to swap, in case of integer, you can do it without using third variable by some mathematical calculation like 
   a= a+b-(b=a);,
 by the way, the above code will never sort the string array.

Comment: Let suppose A=5 and b=10; so you can do it as a= a+b-(b=a); in case of integer or double, but in string, java will never add or minus the string but will concatenate it, apart from that, in java you can not compare a==b where a="abc" and b="bc";

Answer (score 0):

The swapping is useful for changing the order of the array.
Sometimes you might want to sort your array or perhaps randomize it, in that case you'll need to swap elements around to get the desired result.

The third variable is needed because you need to temporarily save one variable.
If you do `arr[i] = arr[j]` then you override the content of `arr[i]` with the content of `arr[j]` so you have lost that value if you haven't saved it.

(You *can* swap values without using a third variable by doing a so-called [XOR swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm) which involves some bit tinkering.)

Answer (score 0):

Well In java it is not necessary to use a 3rd variable to swap 2 variables. But when you use a 3rd variable it is easy.

without using a 3rd variable

```
int a = 10;
int b = 20;

a = a + b; 
b = a - b;
a = a - b;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the same reason why, when two cars drive towards each other on a very narrow street, one of them needs to pull over into a parking spot in order to let the other pass. (Because two cars, or two values, can't occupy the same space at once without at least one of them being destroyed).

The analogy is not precise. It would have been more precise if the first car cloned itself into a parking spot, then the second car drove over the first car, destroying it, then the clone of the first car took off.

(Or, even more precise:

1. First car clones itself into a parking spot
2. Second car clones itself into where the original of the first car is, destroying it
3. Clone of the first car clones itself into where the original of the second car is, destroying it.. and now the two cars have swapped places.

Err, never mind, let's forego on precision for the sake of simplicity.)

Answer (score -1):

It depends upon you... How you want to use it.. As for example, Solving simultaneous equation has number of methods to solve, so in the same way there are number of logic's to be implemented and you can choose whatever you would like to...

And as far as this one concern, I believe using a third variable here will remove the complexity and improve the readability and understanding..