# Generate 0, 1, 2, 3 (even integers) in random order each time, non-repeating, using Math.random()?

Tags: java

How can I generate 0,1,2,3 (even integers) in random order each time the program is run, non-repeating?

As in, run this for loop: for( int x = 1; x < 5; x++ ) with the equation inside, to get 0,1,2,3 each time in a different order.

I am required to use math.random, and cannot figure it out. closest I have is:

```
for( int x = 1; x < 5; x++ )    
{
    double rand = (Math.random() * 4) + 1 ;
    int rand1 = (int) rand;

    if( rand1 == 0 )
    {
        System.out.println( songs[rand1].title );
    }
    if ( rand1 == 1 )
    {
        System.out.println( songs[rand1].title );
    }
    if( rand1 == 2 )
    {
        System.out.println( songs[rand1].title );
    }
    if( rand1 == 3 )
    {
        System.out.println( songs[rand1].title );
    }
}
```

This never gives me the first number.. as it only does 1-4.. which then gives me an error when it goes past 4 I believe.

Desired output is each of the four songs printing out once in a random order every time.

Comment: My [answer on](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19262854/1214236) your previous question pretty much applies here too I guess

Comment: @Alowaniak I have not been taught this method yet.. and really can't write the code for it. And my teacher insists its only using the methods we know :/

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "this method". If you mean the `>>` and `<<`, you can ignore that since that was for even numbers (numbers divisible by 2). If you haven't used (and are not allowed to use) a `List` yet then things get a bit trickier and you're best off with what [rgettman suggest](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19284625/1214236).

Answer (score 2):

First, by adding `1`, you shift the range of your random numbers from 0-3 to 1-4.  Don't add 1.

But to solve your problem, to get non-repeating numbers, you need to shuffle the numbers.  Create an array of `{0, 1, 2, 3}`, and swap the values of 2 random indices many times.

Comment: A probably somewhat easier way is to put them in a list and remove an item at random index (which he can determine by using `Math.random()*list.size()`).

Comment: I used the array int[] nums = { 0, 1, 2, 3 }; ... from there.. how do I randomize the order?

Comment: Didn't you notice that OP casts random `double` to `int`? After that the range is `0-3` as required.

Comment: @Garzhod Use `Math.random`, as you've indicated is required, to select 2 random indices in the range of 0-3.  Swap the values at those indices, e.g. it might to {0, 1, 2, 3} => {3, 1, 2, 0} => {3, 1, 0, 2} => ...

Comment: There is also a ***non-repeat*** requirement.

Comment: @PM77-1 that's the whole point of creating the array and swapping values of 2 random indices

Comment: My Math.random goes as such: double rand = (Math.random() * 3);
            int rand1 = (int) rand;  ... and I am sorry to pry further.. but how would I select two random numbers and replace them?

Comment: @Garzhod `int randIdx1 = (int) (Math.random() * array.length)` create another randIdx2 then swap array[randIdx1] with array[randIdx2]

Comment: @Garzhod First, using `Math.random() * 4` is fine, that yields a range of 0-3.  Or even better, as @Alowaniak suggests, use `array.length` in place of 4.  Call it twice, once for each index to swap.  Swap the values by having a temp variable store the value of index 1, set the value of index 1 to the value of index 2, then set the value of index 2 to the temp variable.

Comment: @Alowaniak I am sorry.. that makes no sense to me. We really haven't been taught that. I am sorry is this is frustrating for you all to answer.. But my knowledge is pretty basic :*

Comment: @Garzhod [read some extra about arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) and check [the swapping part of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217889/swapping-using-a-third-variable-in-java). You'll create two random indices (so just random numbers within the range of your array size) and swap the values of the array at those indices.

Comment: "swap the values of 2 random indices many times": this does not create a uniformly random array (if uniformity is a must).

Answer (score 0):

You are randomize it with this line

```
double rand = (Math.random() * 4) + 1 ;
```

which means "create number from 0 - 1 and multiply with 4), so it creates 0-3.999999999999 and then you add +1, so the value is 1-4.999999999999.

Solution :

```
double rand = (Math.random() * 4)
```

or you can use Random class, which can return int numbers in range :

```
Random r = new Random();
r.nextInt(4);
```

---

The TOTAL SOLUTION WITH NON-REPEATING (sorry, didnt see that earlier)

```
    Random r = new Random();
    boolean end;
    int randomNumber = -1;
    int numberOfNumbers = 4;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        end = false;
        while ( (end == false) && (numberOfNumbers > 1)) {
            int x = r.nextInt(numberOfNumbers);
            if (x != randomNumber) {
                end = true;
                randomNumber = x;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Randomized this nubmer " + randomNumber);            
    }
```

And when you are using `Math.random`

```
    boolean end;
    int randomNumber = -1;
    int numberOfNumbers = 4;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        end = false;
        while ( (end == false) && (numberOfNumbers > 1)) {
            int x = (int) (Math.random()*numberOfNumbers);
            if (x != randomNumber) {
                end = true;
                randomNumber = x;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Randomized this nubmer " + randomNumber);                        
    }
```

Comment: You will **never** get 3 with this formula and subsequent conversion to `int`. `Math.random()` return numbers that `>=0` and `< 1`.

Comment: `Math.random()` `Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and >>less<< than 1.0.` Thus multiplying by 4 will never give you 4.

Comment: tx guys, didnt know that "less" than 1.0

Comment: Should be, "which means "create number from 0 - 1 and multiply with 4), so it creates 0-3 and then you add +1, so the value is 1-4."

Comment: John Zeringue - it is not true, however I rewrote that so it should be now more accurate.